# rails email validation only if present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my user model, I have the field `email`, not required.

I want to validate the field, if and only if it's present. 
It can be blank but if it's present should be validated. 
Well, how it is now, it's never validated.

If I remove the `unless` condition it is always validated (normally)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::
    validates :email, 
                format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }, 
                uniqueness: true,
                unless: lambda { email.nil? }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because it's not `nil`, but an empty string. Use [`allow_blank`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options) instead:

```
validates :email, 
          format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }, 
          uniqueness: true,
          allow_blank: true
```

Comment: thanks, but I already google it and found that solution, doesn't work. In this way it doesn't validate at all

Comment: @FrancescoE. please try running `u = User.new ; u.valid? ; u.errors` in `rails console`,  and append the output to your question.

Comment: no errors about `email` if empty but normal behavior if not, from the console seems to work fine

Comment: and it is actually funny, if I type until the `@` doesn't work, if I go ahead it works.
eg. 
`test@exa`   I got the error
`test@`         no errors
`test`            no errors

Answer (score 2):

if you are using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise),then you dont need to wory about it...if not then you can use the below code in the model:-

```
  EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX,unless: lambda { self.email.blank? }
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, read the last comments on the answer by @janfoeh. Your regex works as mine. Furthermore in rails you should never use `^` and `$` to start and end a regex. Use `\A` and `\z` instead.

p.s. I don't use device and thanks!
p.p.s If you read better, I even don't need the `presence`, but I'll not give you a '-1', I'm in a good mood today

Comment: @FrancescoE. A cursory glance tells me that this more than likely does solve your problem.  Admittedly, that's not the exact regex I'd use, but the validates line appears to be spot-on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71264/discussion-between-francesco-e-and-user3334690).

Comment: looks weird to validate the presence here, then adding a `unless: lambda { self.email.blank? }`